# How can I make this date with a Java Calendar: 31-DEC-99 12.00.00.000000000 AM

Tags: java, calendar

I have been working with a Oracle database and currently on the database this date is the default, as displayed in my database tool:

```
31-DEC-99 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

I am trying to use it as a key on a datebase (bad idea, i know) but cannot match the date.  I have had to switch from java.util.Date to java.util.Calendar for UTC reasons and now I cannot reproduce the above date.  I have tried:

```
new GregorianCalendar(9999, 11, 31, 0, 0) - 31-Dec-99 00.00.00.000000000 AM

Calendar d1 = new GregorianCalendar(9999, 11, 31,0,0);
d1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
d1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
d1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
d1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Same result.
```

I have also tried getting the Long value.  I pulled it from the database (using a getAll) and gotten the long value:

```
Calendar d2 = Calendar.getInstance();
d2.setTime(new Date(253402236000000));
```

but that does not work either.  Any ideas?

I have never gotten a formatted date to read 31-DEC-99 12.00.00.000000000 AM.  Is this a real date or what?

Comment: You keep saying about things that don't work, but without giving any information about what's going wrong. Also note that "99" usually wouldn't mean the year "9999" - it would normally be treated as either 1999 or maybe 2099.

Comment: Added a line above to help out.  Thanks for the tip... (I am trying to use it as a key on a datebase (bad idea, i know) but cannot match the date. )

Comment: I'm not seeing any changes...

Comment: If you want a _formatted_ date (especially looking like that), you're going to need to use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  Although hopefully the value in the Oracle database is actually a date/time/timestamp type, and your ORM package can map it to a Java `Date` (or `java.sql.Timestamp`) automatically.

Comment: Isn't 12am the same as 00:00?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I cannot get a formatted date to look like this.

Comment: Sebastien, you would think that, but it doesn't match.  I think it odd that I can't even get a Calendar object to format to that time...

Comment: I'd change your database tool to use a sensible date format (yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:si.ss TZR I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(9999, 11, 31, 0, 0);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy h.mm.ss.000000000 a");
    System.out.println(format.format(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: GAAA! I believe I was not setting the timezone.  That is why it wan't matching.  Hibernate converts everything!  This is the date format that I was using, however, it would not display correctly because I was using "dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a" which is the 24 hour clock, i believe.  Thanks!