# Date format of given String

Tags: java, datetime

What format the below date is in?

```
21-MAY-11 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

i tried below but did not work. any clue?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter_1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.HH.mm.SSSSSSSSS a");
```

Comment: It's (presumably) hours.minutes.seconds.fractionOfSecond, not hours.hours.minutes.fractionOfSecond.

Comment: Related: [Converting java.sql.Timestamp to Instant Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986138/converting-java-sql-timestamp-to-instant-time). Also related: [How can I make this date with a Java Calendar: 31-DEC-99 12.00.00.000000000 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403306/how-can-i-make-this-date-with-a-java-calendar-31-dec-99-12-00-00-000000000-am). Apparently the same format, only the old and outdated date and time API asked about.

Comment: Is that May 11, 2021, or is it 21 May 2011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy Turner in the comments is right.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS a", Locale.ROOT);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
String format = fmt.format(localDateTime);
System.out.println(format);
```

Comment: I think that you want `dd-MMM-yy` as in the question. You also want to supply a locale to the formatter. Otherwise a very fine answer.

Comment: Is it faction-of-second or nano-of-seconds?

   S  ->  fraction-of-second (e.g. 978) and   n  ->  nano-of-second (e.g.  987654321)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @GauravkumarSingh As long as there are exactly 9 decimals, either `SSSSSSSSS` or `nnnnnnnnn` will work. For fewer than 9 picking the right letter is of importance, you are right.

Comment: Apart from the problems pointed out by @OleV.V. ,  there is another problem with your pattern. Instead of `hh` (the symbol for the 12-hour or AM/PM time format), you have used `HH` (the symbol for the 24-Hour time format).

Answer (score 3):

There is no in-built pattern that you can use for it. You can build a case-insensitive `DateTimeFormatter` with `Locale.ENGLISH` to parse this string.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "21-MAY-11 12.00.00.000000000 AM";
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("uu-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-11T00:00
```

Here, you can use `yy` instead of `uu` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CakiW1)

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Use this one to format datetime.

```
DateFormat('dd-MMM-yy hh.HH.mm.SSSSSSSSS a').format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: Which `DateFormat` class and which language are those? The question wisely asked about Java and `DateTimeFormatter` (from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), so if you wanted to suggest something else, I think you should tell us what would be wrong with the asker’s choice or whether there are any advantages of your suggestion? I also invite to publish an example result from your code line, also because I am not from the outset 100 % assured that your code is correct.